# Why is this exception thrown in the visual studio C compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio, exception, printf, getchar

I am trying to get more adept and my C programming and I was attempting to test out displaying a character from the input stream while inside of the loop that is getting the character.  I am using the `getchar` method.

I am getting an exception thrown at the time that the `printf` statement in my code is present.  (If I comment out the `printf` line in this function, the exception is not thrown).

> Exception: Unhandled exception at
>   0x611c91ad (msvcr90d.dll) in
>   firstOS.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00002573.

Here is the code...  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

PS.  I am using the `stdio.h` library.

```
/*getCommandPromptNew - obtains a string command prompt.*/
void getCommandPromptNew(char s[], int lim){    

    int i, c;

    for(i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i){
        s[i] = c;
        printf('%s', c);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

```
printf('%s', c);
```

to

```
printf("%c", c);
```

If you wish to print the entire string at the ***end*** of the loop you need to terminate it with a `NULL` char as:

```
s[i] = 0;
```

and then you can print it as:

```
printf("%s", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that you should check is: are you allocated memory for s[] or not.
Second: printf("%c", c); // I can suppose that %s - is waiting for null terminated string.
Third: maybe problem with "" vs '' in printf().